# Can't Call Segue from Async Function like XMLParser

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, segue, nsxmlparser

In my VC, I call an XML web service. Based on the results, I'm likely to segue to another VC. I've removed the business logic from my code and left only the part that matters. This is the short version of my code:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "userDidRequestReset", sender: nil)
}
```

I even have a prepareForSegue and it gets called:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResetViewController
    destinationVC.username = txtUsername.text!
}
```

However, with or without that prepareForSegue, it doesn't actually segue to the next VC. Why isn't it working?

**Note:** I've also tried adding self. before the performSegue, but still no luck.

**Edit:** my `performSegue` worked just fine in other places such as button action, just not in XMLParser functions.

Comment: What is the base class of XMLParser?

Comment: `I even have a prepareForSegue and it gets called:`, so it means prepareForSegue func calls, but what did you get in `destinationVC` ? This verifies the segue identifier issue.

Comment: @NeverHopeless I've tried putting `performSegue(withIdentifier: "userDidRequestReset", sender: nil) ` in other places such as in a button's action and it worked fine. It only didn't work from within the XMLParser's functions.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS The XMLParser is running in the class of a VC. `class ForgotViewController: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps perform segue from main thread will do the job:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "userDidRequestReset", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had the feeling it had something to do with it being async. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gald to help :)